Taipy callback function with parameters
in the following taipy code, the intended functionality is that when the image is clicked a paramter cat should be passed to select_category function, but i couldn't get it to work without error:
--- 1 warning(s) were found for page 'TaiPy_partials_0'  ---

Warning 1: image.on_action: select_category(cat is not a function.

<|{images_folder+r'\juice1.png'}|image|on_action=select_category(cat)|>
def select_category(state,cat):
print(cat)
what is the right why to pass parameters/argument to the function from once an image is clicked?

Don't pass cat as a property of your function. The proper syntax is:
<|{images_folder+r'\juice1.png'}|image|on_action=select_category|>

`
You should retrieve cat in your state if you first defined it somewhere in your script.
cat = "your default value" 

def select_category(state):
    print(state.cat)



Thank you for your answer.
the intended behavior is that once an image clicked the cat value should change based on the clicked image and select_category function should capture that and do action based on the new cat value linked to clicked image.

You can do whatever you want inside select_catgory. Based on what should the cat value change?

if there are more than two images with on_action set to the same set_category function. how the set_categeroy function will know which image is clicked?
<|{images_folder+r'\juice1.png'}|image|on_action=select_category|>
<|{images_folder+r'\juice2.png'}|image|on_action=select_category|>
def select_category(state):
if image1 do something
else if image2 do something eles

can any one help

You put an id to your image. This is then returned to the callback <|{images_folder+r'\juice1.png'}|image|on_action=select_category|id=juice|>     def select_category(state, id):    if id=="juice":...

it works, i put  in the f string
